# What happens to power ups after death

Tags: hero-academy

In Hero Academy, if I lose one of my units and step over him in the next turn (so I save him), do I also save any equipment he's carrying? Or, is the equipment lost, but the hero is saved?

Comment: What do you mean by "step over him"?  If you heal a knocked out unit, none of the equipment is lost.  If you use the Team Fortress 2 respawn item, the unit is saved, but loses any upgrades provided by the Engineer.

Comment: When I step over one of my downed units, I save him, no? That's what I mean by saving a unit.

Comment: If you do not use a healer (or an item that provides healing) to revive a knocked out unit then the knocked out unit disappears at the end of your turn and is lost forever (including all equipment on him or her).

Comment: Yeah, I may take this question down. It looks like if I step over a friendly downed unit, as mentioned in the question, the ally doesn't go back into the repository, but it gives an offensive bonus... can anyone confirm this? (I wasn't able to see any other direct consequences.)

Comment: No offensive bonus unless the downed unit was on an attack tile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the unit and the equipment are lost when you stomp your own unit.  If you want to save the unit and equipment you'll need to revive them with a healer or an item that has that ability.

Answer (score 1):

Stepping over a unit that is "knocked out" does nothing to the unit. When a unit is "knocked out" they retain all their power-ups and equipment.  If they are revived on that turn, there is no loss at all.  If they are not revived on that turn, the unit and all of their equipment is lost.

Reviving is different for each race of heroes. For example, in the case of Team Fortress, a `respawn token` may be considered a "revive", but it actually resets the hero and places it back on the rack. All power ups are removed in that case.

The only offensive bonus I know of given for a downed unit is for the "Tribe" race. When one of their units is "stomped" by the other team, every "Tribe" hero is given an offensive bonus.